# Reloading partial in an rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial, unobtrusive-javascript

I want to reload a partial every 3 seconds on a 'new'-view in my rails app.

I have this in my `new.html.erb`

```
<h1>Controller#new</h1>
This is my static content
<%= render partial: 'dynamic' %>
More Static content
```

How do I get this partial reloaded every 3 seconds? Do I have to use unobtrusive javascript for this? How can I achieve this through ujs?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Put partial in div

```
   <div class="dynamic"><%= render partial: 'dynamic' %></div>
```

You can do it by using jquery like this

```
       $(document).ready(
         function() {
          setInterval(function() {
            $('.dynamic').load('/controller_name/action_name');
        }, 3000);
    });
```

Now refresh partial in controller action for load new content

```
         def action_name
            render :partial => "directory_name/dynamic"
         end
```

It will sure work.........

Comment: Thank you, please note this is very helpful

Comment: How do you pass variables to the partial? This doesn't work: render partial: "courses/navigation_buttons", current_slide: (at)current_slide, course: (at)course