# how to render partial in rails with jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been trying to follow another SO answer with no luck.

My main goal is to refresh the partial when I click a div

Maybe someone can help trouble shoot. It must be a syntax error (maybe..).

in my gobal.js I have:

```
$('.reset').on('click', function(){
      $(".friend").load('/users_controller/load_friend');
});
```

in my users_controller i have :

```
      def load_friend
        render :partial => 'friend_image'
      end
```

in my markup / haml I have:

```
 .friend
    =render 'friend_image'
```

the file / partial is under the users controller directory, and is named:

```
_friend_image.html.haml
```

where have I gone wrong? Let me know if you need more info.

---

error message:

### localhost:3000/users_controller/load_friend 404 (Not Found)

this is the original example I have tried to follow: 
[SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539143/reloading-partial-in-an-rails-app)

Comment: show some error messages?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/users_controller/load_friend 404 (Not Found)

Comment: the click is trying to load the partial it seems, but i'm not pointing to it correctly.. or did something wrong in the controller maybe.

Comment: Have you added users_controller/load_friend action to routes.rb?

Comment: run `rake routes` check if your route `users_controller/load_friend` exists

Comment: Must be the issue. Excuse the noob question, i've mainly used node and am trying to help out with a project on the front end, but would this be the proper way to setup the route:                                                            get 'load_friend', to: 'users#page_partial_loads_on'  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `$(".friend").load('/users_controller/load_friend');` to `$(".friend").load('/users/load_friend');`